# my app often causes chrome tab crash - how I can fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, backbone.js

My app uses a lot of javascript with backbone.js that manipulate DOM triggered by various events. It sometimes causes tab crash on Google Chrome(just tab crash and not the whole chrome crash). We have been investigating what is actually causing this issue, but there is no clue. We monitored memory by tab from chrome task manager, but crash happens even when memory use is small.

Is there any way to debug this kind of issue? We have no clue in identifying what the problem is.

**UPDATE**

The problem is that it is not easy to replicate the crash intentionally. It sometimes happen to some users. And those users normally repeatedly experience that (typically after clicking submit button). On the other hand, for other users, Chrome still works fine even though the tab starts to use over 200M memory after complicated DOM manipulation. Using profiling tool on developers tool might be one way, however it looks really a lot of work till identifying the issue. Would be great if somebody knows efficient way to identify what the problem is...

What we also know is that we have been suffering from memory leak. So, we started to unbind events once DOM the events are bound to got deleted. That helped us avoid huge memory usage as long as we monitor from task manager. However, we do not know we have done this well enough and it has something to do with the tab crash...

Comment: Did you ever manage to successfully fix this? I'm facing a similar problem at the minute myself. Random console logging in a complex large web app when you can't reliable cause it to crash is hugely impractical, but the only solution I've seen on SO so far.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the developer tools and click on the Console tab and add some `console.log(message);` throughout your code to see where it makes it before it crashes.  Without more information there isn't much else to do.

Comment: i see. however, as i updated the original question, it is difficult to intentionally replicate the crash... so, wondering if there is any efficient way or tools to approach this.